# CPPUTEST memory deletion

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cpputest

I have the code as below:

```
char* Add()
{
    p = new char[10];
    return p;
}
```

and I use CPPUTEST with the test code as below:

```
TEST(MyTestGroup, TestAdd_1)
{
    p = Add(); // the above function
    delete p;
}
```

But the error is: "Allocation/deallocation type mismatch"

I don't know why, please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which programming language is this? (How) is `p` declared?

Answer (score 3):

> But the error is: "Allocation/deallocation type mismatch"

That's because you allocate an array, but deallocate a single object.

```
TEST(MyTestGroup, TestAdd_1)
{
    p = Add(); // the above function
    delete[] p; // <--- Use correct delete for arrays
}
```